# Widfly 9.0.2 não está inicializando em modo debug

Tags: java, angularjs, spring, jboss, wildfly

No controller da minha aplicação, tenho um método com uma requisição POST, antes ele era um método void, sem retorno, mas alterei para que ele já me retornasse os registros gerados, após essa alteração, o servidor da minha aplicação, o widfly 9.0.2 não se inicia mais, trava e dá timeout na inicialização, quando está inicializando o "Mojarra 2.2.12" no modo Debug.

Método:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/gerarNotificacao", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public List<Notificacao> gerarNotificacao(@RequestBody NotificacaoConsulta notificacao) throws Exception {

    List<Conta> contas = contaService.consultaContasDebitos(notificacao);

    return notificacaoSimulacaoService.gerarNotificacoes(contas);

}
```

Exceção:

```
``11:10:03,926 INFO  [javax.enterprise.resource.webcontainer.jsf.config] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 64) Inicializando Mojarra 2.2.12-jbossorg-2 20150729-1131 para o contexto '/divida'
11:13:43,299 ERROR [org.jboss.as.controller.management-operation] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYCTL0348: Timeout after [300] seconds waiting for service container stability. Operation will roll back. Step that first updated the service container was 'add' at address '[
    ("core-service" => "management"),
    ("management-interface" => "http-interface")
]'
11:13:44,147 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.deployers.jdbc] (MSC service thread 1-8) WFLYJCA0019: Stopped Driver service with driver-name = PlataformaLogpro.war_org.postgresql.Driver_9_1
11:13:44,287 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.undertow] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 70) WFLYUT0022: Unregistered web context: /laboratorio
11:13:44,291 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.undertow] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 69) WFLYUT0022: Unregistered web context: /divida
11:13:46,573 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-6) WFLYSRV0028: Stopped deployment dividaativa (runtime-name: dividaativa.war) in 3108ms
11:13:46,581 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-5) WFLYSRV0028: Stopped deployment laboratorio (runtime-name: laboratorio.war) in 3101ms
11:13:48,466 ERROR [org.jboss.as.controller.management-operation] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYCTL0190: Step handler org.jboss.as.server.DeployerChainAddHandler$FinalRuntimeStepHandler@34e5c4c3 for operation {"operation" => "add-deployer-chains","address" => []} at address [] failed handling operation rollback -- java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException: java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException
    at org.jboss.as.controller.OperationContextImpl.waitForRemovals(OperationContextImpl.java:396)
    at org.jboss.as.controller.AbstractOperationContext$Step.handleResult(AbstractOperationContext.java:1384)
    at org.jboss.as.controller.AbstractOperationContext$Step.finalizeInternal(AbstractOperationContext.java:1332)
    at org.jboss.as.controller.AbstractOperationContext$Step.finalizeStep(AbstractOperationContext.java:1292)
    at org.jboss.as.controller.AbstractOperationContext$Step.access$300(AbstractOperationContext.java:1180)
    at org.jboss.as.controller.AbstractOperationContext.handleContainerStabilityFailure(AbstractOperationContext.java:964)
    at org.jboss.as.controller.AbstractOperationContext.doCompleteStep(AbstractOperationContext.java:590)
    at org.jboss.as.controller.AbstractOperationContext.completeStepInternal(AbstractOperationContext.java:354)
    at org.jboss.as.controller.AbstractOperationContext.executeOperation(AbstractOperationContext.java:330)
    at org.jboss.as.controller.OperationContextImpl.executeOperation(OperationContextImpl.java:1183)
    at org.jboss.as.controller.ModelControllerImpl.boot(ModelControllerImpl.java:453)
    at org.jboss.as.controller.AbstractControllerService.boot(AbstractControllerService.java:327)
    at org.jboss.as.controller.AbstractControllerService.boot(AbstractControllerService.java:313)
    at org.jboss.as.server.ServerService.boot(ServerService.java:384)
    at org.jboss.as.server.ServerService.boot(ServerService.java:359)
    at org.jboss.as.controller.AbstractControllerService$1.run(AbstractControllerService.java:271)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

11:13:48,604 ERROR [org.jboss.as.controller.client] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYCTL0190: Step handler org.jboss.as.server.DeployerChainAddHandler$FinalRuntimeStepHandler@34e5c4c3 for operation {"operation" => "add-deployer-chains","address" => []} at address [] failed handling operation rollback -- java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException
11:13:53,698 ERROR [org.jboss.as.controller.management-operation] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYCTL0190: Step handler org.jboss.as.domain.management.security.SecurityRealmAddHandler$ServiceInstallStepHandler@616ff021 for operation {"address" => [("core-service" => "management"),("security-realm" => "ApplicationRealm")],"operation" => "add","map-groups-to-roles" => undefined} at address [
    ("core-service" => "management"),
    ("security-realm" => "ApplicationRealm")
] failed handling operation rollback -- java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException: java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException
    at org.jboss.as.controller.OperationContextImpl.waitForRemovals(OperationContextImpl.java:396)
    at org.jboss.as.controller.AbstractOperationContext$Step.handleResult(AbstractOperationContext.java:1384)
    at org.jboss.as.controller.AbstractOperationContext$Step.finalizeInternal(AbstractOperationContext.java:1332)
    at org.jboss.as.controller.AbstractOperationContext$Step.finalizeStep(AbstractOperationContext.java:1307)
    at org.jboss.as.controller.AbstractOperationContext$Step.access$300(AbstractOperationContext.java:1180)
    at org.jboss.as.controller.AbstractOperationContext.handleContainerStabilityFailure(AbstractOperationContext.java:964)
    at org.jboss.as.controller.AbstractOperationContext.doCompleteStep(AbstractOperationContext.java:590)
    at org.jboss.as.controller.AbstractOperationContext.completeStepInternal(AbstractOperationContext.java:354)
    at org.jboss.as.controller.AbstractOperationContext.executeOperation(AbstractOperationContext.java:330)
    at org.jboss.as.controller.OperationContextImpl.executeOperation(OperationContextImpl.java:1183)
    at org.jboss.as.controller.ModelControllerImpl.boot(ModelControllerImpl.java:453)
    at org.jboss.as.controller.AbstractControllerService.boot(AbstractControllerService.java:327)
    at org.jboss.as.controller.AbstractControllerService.boot(AbstractControllerService.java:313)
    at org.jboss.as.server.ServerService.boot(ServerService.java:384)
    at org.jboss.as.server.ServerService.boot(ServerService.java:359)
    at org.jboss.as.controller.AbstractControllerService$1.run(AbstractControllerService.java:271)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
``
```

Comment: Você usa maven? Se sim, tente executar o "Maven Clean" e depois um "Maven Update". Caso não use maven, tente limpar o projeto no servidor.

Comment: Utilizo o maven, mas não funcionou, limpar o projeto no servidor já havia tentado, também não funcionou.

Comment: Retira os Breakpoints que funciona.

Answer (score 0):

O wildfly tem um timeout padrão de 300ms. Tente aumentar o timeout do jboss adicionando a opção **"blocking.timeout"**.

Para isso altere o arquivo **bin/standalone.conf.bat** (local pode variar dependendo da sua instalação do wildfly)

Adicione a linha

```
set "JAVA_OPTS=%JAVA_OPTS% -Djboss.as.management.blocking.timeout=600
```

O valor do timeout deve ser alterado de acordo com o desejado

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta, agora está inicializando, mas inicializa em 8 minutos, é muito tempo, antes inicializava em menos de 1 minuto, alguma sugestão ou pode ser alguma coisa no código?

Comment: Varias fatores podem contribuir para esse problema, um deles pode ser memória da máquina, mas para saber o problema exato é necessário ter mais informações sobre sua aplicação. Nesse caso talvez seja melhor abrir uma nova pergunta sobre a lentidão e colocar mais informações com memório, cpu entre outras.

Comment: Antes de minha ultima alteração, a inicialização era instantânea, levava 40 segundos para iniciar o servidor wildfly, como estava antes:

@RequestMapping(value = "/gerarNotificacao", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public void gerarNotificacao(@RequestBody NotificacaoConsulta notificacao) throws Exception {

    List<Conta> contas = contaService.consultaContasDebitos(notificacao);

    notificacaoSimulacaoService.gerarNotificacoes(contas);

}

Comment: De uma olhada no arquivo de log do WildFly para ver se tem algo lá. Pelo tempo que aparece nas linhas do log, talvez de para ver onde que ele está travando ou demorando tanto para inicializar.